# How to set proxy host name for IBM API Designer?

Tags: ibm-cloud, strongloop, apiconnect

I started IBM API Connect API Designer using command `apic edit` behind a reverse proxy. Because the API Designer performs OAuth against Bluemix and the callback is set to 127.0.0.1:3000 by default, the callback cannot pass through the proxy. One [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_cli_model_create_editor.html?cp=SSMNED_5.0.0%2F3-5-0-2) showed how to change the port, but how can I pass the proxy host name to API Designer OAuth module?

Comment: Have you already tried setting env proxy variables before starting apic client? On Linux/Mac you could set export http_proxy=http://user:pw@proxy:port and the same with https

Comment: Yes. But that env is forward proxy, not reverse proxy.

Comment: Sorry, I am missing the usage of a reverse proxy when connecting to an external service. 
Reverse proxy is to make internal service available to external client connections (and eventually to add a caching layer), in your case you have a client connecting externally to a server

Comment: You should be able to set the host to the reverse proxy by exporting the HOST variable.  export HOST=reverse_proxy_ip  That in should set the call back to that address.  But that will also override where the designer starts (localhost:9000), so you might need to tweak the reverse proxy.

Comment: I already tried HOST and as you said, it controls which ip does designer listen on, not for passing reverse proxy config to the designer. The predecessor - slc arc doesn't suffer the problem because it doesn't use OAuth.

Comment: @abbr are you still having this issue? if you were able to solve it can you please add an answer below.

Comment: @JoshuaAlger, I ended up using slc/lb CLI. It allows me to stay in FOSS lb world, which is all I needed. I am now convinced apic is more of a bait towards $$$ bluemix than merely the next gen.